# How to set TTL for a specific Couchbase document using spring-data-couchbase?

Tags: java, couchbase, ttl, spring-data-couchbase, content-expiration

How to set TTL (Time to Live) for a specific couchbase document using spring-data-couchbase?
I know there is way to set expiry time using Document notation as follows
@Document(expiry = 10)

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/couchbase.entity.html

It will set TTL for all the documents save through the Entity class.

But it seems there is way to set expiration(TTL) time for a specific document
"Get and touch: Fetch a specified document and update the document expiration."
mentioned in 
http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dev-guide-3.0/read-write.html

How can I achieve above functionality through spring-data-couchbase
Even If I can achieve the functionality using Java SDK, would be fine.

Any help.....

Answer (score 5):

Using Spring data couchbase, this is a simple way you can configure ttl per document.

```
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected List<String> bootstrapHosts() {
        return Arrays.asList("localhost");
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketName() {
        return "default";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketPassword() {
        return "password1";
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingCouchbaseConverter mappingCouchbaseConverter() throws Exception {
        MappingCouchbaseConverter converter = new ExpiringDocumentCouchbaseConverter(couchbaseMappingContext());
        converter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
        return converter;
    }


    class ExpiringDocumentCouchbaseConverter extends MappingCouchbaseConverter {

        /**
         * Create a new {@link MappingCouchbaseConverter}.
         *
         * @param mappingContext the mapping context to use.
         */
        public ExpiringDocumentCouchbaseConverter(MappingContext<? extends CouchbasePersistentEntity<?>, CouchbasePersistentProperty> mappingContext) {
            super(mappingContext);
        }

        // Setting custom TTL on documents.
        @Override
        public void write(final Object source, final CouchbaseDocument target) {
            super.write(source, target);
            if (source instanceof ClassContainingTTL) {
                target.setExpiration(((ClassContainingTTL) source).getTimeToLive());
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Spring-Data-Couchbase, you cannot set a TTL on a particular instance. Inserting (mutating) and setting the TTL in one go would be quite complicated given the transcoding steps that are hidden away in the `CouchbaseTemplate` `save` method.

However, if what you want to do is just update the TTL of an already persisted document (which is what `getAndTouch` does), there is a way that doesn't involve any transcoding and so can be applied easily:

- From the `CouchbaseTemplate`, get access to the underlying SDK client via `getCouchbaseClient()` *(**note** for now sdc is built on top of the previous generation of SDK, `1.4.x`, but there'll be a preview of sdc-2.0 soon ;) )*
- Using the SDK, perform a `touch` operation on the document's ID, give it the new TTL
- The `touch()` method returns an `OperationFuture` (it is async), so make sure to either block on it or consider the touch done only if notified so in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

As of `spring-data-couchbase:4.3.0` the code should look like `yourRepository.getOperations().getCouchbaseClientFactory().getCollection(null).touch(id, ttl)` or alternatively this can be done through `CouchbaseTemplate` as `couchbaseTemplate.getCollection(null).touch(id, ttl)`

Answer (score 0):

findById() has a withExpiry() method that results in getAndTouch() being used and the expiration being set

User foundUser = couchbaseTemplate.findById(User.class).withExpiry(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).one(id);