# How to tell when a document was created/updated in Couchbase?

Tags: couchbase

I am using spring data to fetch couchbase documents.  I assume the document expiry cannot be set as a configurable value externalized in a property file (@Document(expiry = )) based on answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528665/how-to-set-ttl-for-a-specific-couchbase-document-using-spring-data-couchbase)

However can I define a view in cochbase and have query to return only the documents which have been created in the past 15 minutes? I don't want to save additional information regarding date in my document and I am looking to see if there is any meta data that can be used for this purpose

```
   function (doc, meta) {
    if(doc._class=="com.customer.types.CustomerInfo" ){
      emit(meta.id, doc);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go into the webconsole and create a development view, you can have a look at what metadata are available using the preview:

```
emit(meta.id, meta)
```

This gives us

```
{
  "id": "someKey",
  "rev": "3-00007098b90700000000000002000000",
  "seq": "3",
  "vb": "56",
  "expiration": 0,
  "flags": 33554432,
  "type": "json"
}
```

So as you can see, there is no explicit metadata that you can use to tell if a doc has been created/updated in the last 15 minutes.

**Side note**: the id of the doc will always be part of the view's response so emitting it is a bit redundant. More importantly, **don't emit the whole doc as a value** (if in doubt on what to emit as the second field, just emit `null`). This value field is stored in the index, so that means that you are basically storing your document's content twice (once in the primary store, once in the view index)!